# Fade in and then out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am just starting to learn to use jQuery now, and I am experimenting with fading images in and out.  I would like to fade an image to half opacity when I hover over it.  Then, only after I remove my mouse of the image, the image reverts back to full opacity.  Right now, I am using a callback function to fade the image back in, but it is performed immediately after the fade out occurs, not when my mouse leaves the image.  Does anyone have some hints as to what is going on?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").mouseover(function(event){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5, function(){
      $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0)}
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").on('mouseover', function(event){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0)    
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2uS8r/2/#update).

Answer (score 3):

You may use two events with `on`. I would advise against using `hover` since it's [about to get deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731).

```
$("img").on({
    mouseover: function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', .5); },
    mouseout: function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1); }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gT4vC/

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing class or id name here..

```
$("img").mouseover(function(event){
```

instead of this use below line
    $(".img").mouseover(function(event){

specify class or id for mouse over event.

Comment: Selector can also be html tag names.

Answer (score 1):

User `.hover()` function, its accepts two parameter, one for mouseenter event and another for the mouseleave event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(function(event){
         $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
      },
      function() {
         $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
      });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syaPr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").mouseenter(function(event) {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTzTH/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("img").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
  }, function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  Change the uppercase constants at the top to get the timing right for the effect you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var FADEOUT_TIME = 500;
    var FADEIN_TIME = 500;
    $("img").on({
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(FADEIN_TIME, 1);
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(FADEOUT_TIME, 0.5);
        }
    });
});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/dTMNH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").on({
    mouseover: function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', .8); },
    mouseout: function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1); }
});
});
```

here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwNaM/)

**Update**

or you can also use the css property `opacity`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseover(function(){
       $('img').css('opacity','0.4');
    });

    $("img").mouseout(function(){
       $('img').css('opacity','1');
    })
});
```

as here is [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwNaM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").mouseenter(function(event){
      $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5).mouseleave(function(){
              $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: if modification needed please inform.